# Custom class that can be applied to every UITextField - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

Im very new to programming and am making a project that will have many UITextFields. I want to have the text fields only have a border on the bottom for a cleaner look, and I found some code here that is supposed to make that happen.

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

How can I make a class so that every UItext field I place in the storyboard I can simply make it part of said class? I don't want to copy and paste this code for each UITextField. And is there a way to do it where I could individually edit the placeholder text for each UITextfield this class is applied to?

Comment: You could subclass UITextField and add all the styles in there.  If you are using storyboards you can the just give it the custom class name you made.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake, but I made a file and in it is 
"class BottomBorderTextField: UITextField {}" with the code in my original post between the brackets. But on the"border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor" line I get an error that says expected declaration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it's very easy just enter this code in under any class only one time

```
    @IBDesignable
    open class customUITextField: UITextField {

        func setup() {
            let border = CALayer()
            let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)  
        setup()
    }
}
```

[image]

In "Setup" function put all customizations you want.

After that back to design and choose it in all TextField you have and Run

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your implementation works perfectly! I was wondering if had any idea why the border line on the bottom doesn't extend the full width in my project? It only goes about 3/4 of the width of the UITextField.

Comment: please show me your code, but for the above code, it fills 100% of Textfield as appear in the photo.

Comment: My code is exactly the same as what you've provided which is why it is confusing me. I created a file using cocoa touch class for a UITextField, and then copied in the code exactly, then I made it that class the class for the UITextField in the story board, but for some reason it only goes 3/4 of the way across.

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the issue but make sure of  "width: self.frame.size.width"

Comment: Closing Xcode and switching the simulator seems to have fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - width, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        layer.addSublayer(border)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

To simplify your border code you could do this:

```
layer.borderWidth = 2.0
layer.masksToBounds = true
```