# How to make custom TextField in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I make a custom text field to look like this [TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZGhH.jpg) because i am confused as to what modifiers i need to add to the standard textfield

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom class that can be applied to every UITextField - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681626/custom-class-that-can-be-applied-to-every-uitextfield-swift)

Comment: i need swiftUI not swift Uikit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Divider`, `.overlay` and `.textFieldStyle(.plain)`

```
@State private var age: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("Hey John, how old are you?")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .heavy))

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TextField("Age", text: $age)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .heavy))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .accentColor(.black)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 60, bottom: 0, trailing: 60))
                .overlay(Divider(), alignment: .bottom)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 50, bottom: 0, trailing: 50))
    }
}
```